# Difference between two times that are saved as strings using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, timepicker

I have two time picker jquery controls that have time in the format of "10 AM", "11 AM", "12 PM" etc.. How do I get the difference between these two time selections.

For example, if I pick 10 AM in first control, 1 PM in second control, I need to the difference in hours which is 3. How can I do this in javascript.

```
var FirstTime = container.find('#1time').val();
var SecondTime = container.find('#2time').val();

alert(FirstTime); // 11 AM
alert(SecondTime);// 1 PM

var diff = (SecondTime - FirstTime); // Need value of 3 here..
```

I can have the time picker controls set to military time format and parse it to get the numbers out and get the difference. But thats not an option. I understand the numbers are getting saved as strings with the AM and PM attached.. is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function timeDiff( first, second ) {
    var f = first.split(' '), s = second.split(' ');

    if( first == '12 AM' ) f[0] = '0';
    if( first == '12 PM' ) f[1] = 'AM';
    if( second == '12 AM' ) s[0] = '24';
    if( second == '12 PM' ) s[1] = 'AM';

    f[0] = parseInt( f[0], 10 ) + (f[1] == 'PM' ? 12 : 0);
    s[0] = parseInt( s[0], 10 ) + (s[1] == 'PM' ? 12 : 0);

    return s[0] - f[0];
}

var FirstTime = container.find('#1time').val();
var SecondTime = container.find('#2time').val();

alert(FirstTime); // 11 AM
alert(SecondTime);// 1 PM

var diff = timeDiff( FirstTime, SecondTime );
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qUW2R/1/)

Comment: Doesn't work. You must use parentheses around `f[1] == 'PM' ? 12 : 0;`

Comment: @some Yep thanks just realized, I had changed the position of the assignment operator

Comment: If `12 AM` is midnight (according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight)) and one are using '12 AM' and '1 AM' the result is -11 instead of expected 1.

Comment: @some That should already be fixed, see the updated version and give it a try. Hopefully I caught all the edge cases. I assume the time-picker doesnt allow the second time to be before the first time

Comment: @zvenue what is the range on the time-pickers? how do you show midnight (day 1) on the first picker and midnight (day 2) on the second picker? i.e. a time difference of 24 hours

Comment: '11PM' and '12 AM' gives -11, expected 1 or -23 (depending if it is the beginning or ending of the day)

Comment: Ah, see that you fixed it now.

Comment: I can control range in the time picker, and luckily for now I dont have midnight hours.. but might in future, this will be useful. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
var time1;
var time2;
if (FirstTime.split(' ')[1] === "PM") {
    time1 = parseInt(FirstTime.split(' ')[0])+ 12;
}else{
    time1 = parseInt(FirstTime.split(' ')[0])
}

if (SecondTime.split(' ')[1] === "PM") {
    time2 = parseInt(SecondTime.split(' ')[0])+ 12
}else{
    time2 = parseInt(SecondTime.split(' ')[0])
}

diff = time2 - time1;
```

Comment: something off here.. thanks for the response though.. I like the general idea and how to do this.. with minor tweak this will work fine.

Comment: You code doesn't handle '12 AM' and '12 PM' correctly: `'1 AM'-'12 AM'=-11`, `'12 PM'-'1 PM'=-11`, `'11 PM'-'12 AM'=-11`. It's also a lot of repeated code. Btw, without a radix to `parseInt' the number could be interpreted as an octal number if it's run on an older javascript engine (and if the number starts with a zero).

Answer (score 2):

Since the 12h clock notation don't distinguish between the midnight at the start of a particular day and the midnight at its end, the function below assumes that `12 AM` means *the start of the day* if it is used in the first variable, and *the end of the day* if is used in the second variable. That means that `'12 AM' - '12 AM' = 24`.

```
function timeDiff( first, second ) {
  function to24h(value) {
    value = value.split(' ');
    return (value[0] % 12) + (value[1]==='PM' ? 12:0);
  }
  return (to24h(second)||24) - to24h(first);
}
```